# When is the difference between two triangular numbers a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

When is the difference between two triangular numbers a prime number? and what is the rule? I have tried drawing it out,graphs and tables however I have been unsuccessful in finding an answer.

Source: AS Level maths

Comment: What did you mean by "two triangular numbers a prime number"?

Comment: You will need the formula for triangular numbers. Graphs and tables wont tell you if a number is prime or not.

Comment: Every prime number $p$ is a difference of two triangular numbers by setting $p = \sum_{n=1}^p n - \sum_{n=1}^{p-1} n$. You want to know what are the conditions for the two triangular numbers in order for the difference to be prime?

Comment: @user2566092: that's not the only possibility: e.g., $7 = ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) - (1 + 2)$.

Comment: So the triangular numbers don't have to be consecutive?

Answer (score 3):

You would do better to note that a triangle number is of the form $\cfrac {n(n-1)}2$ and explore the difference of two triangle numbers with $n\gt m$ which is $$\cfrac {n(n-1)}2-\cfrac {m(m-1)}2$$ Hint: can you factorise the expression which arises? You will need to take care with the factor $2$ in the denominator and deal with the case of the prime being $2$, which is even, but small enough to look at on its own.